# What is the best way to store job level data from Spring batch partition worker steps?

Tags: spring-batch, partitioning

I have a spring batch job. It processes a large number of items. For each item, it calls an external service (assume a stored procedure or a REST service. This does some business calculations and updates a database. These results are used to generate some analytical reports.). Each item is independent, so I am partitioning the external calls in 10 partitions in the same JVM. For example, if there are 50 items to process, each partition will have 50/10 = 5 items to process.
This external service can result a `SUCCESS` or `FAILURE` return code. All the business logic is encapsulated in this external service and therefore worker step is a tasklet which just calls the external service and receives a `SUCCESS`/`FAILURE` flag.  I want to store all the `SUCCESS`/`FAILURE` flag for each item and get them when job is over. These are the approaches I can think of:

1. Each worker step can store the item and its `SUCCESS`/`FAILURE` in a collection and store that in job execution context. Spring batch persists the execution context and I can retrieve it at the end of the job. This is the most naïve way, and causes thread contention when all 10 worker steps try to access and modify the same collection.
2. The concurrent exceptions in 1st approach can be avoided by using a concurrent collection like `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. But this is too costly and the whole purpose of partitioning is defeated when each worker step is waiting to access the list.
3. I can write the item ID and success/failure to an external table or message queue. This will avoid the issues in above 2 approaches but we are going out of spring bath framework to achieve this. I mean we are not using spring batch job execution context and using an external database or message queue.

Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: In option 3, what do you mean by `but we are going out of spring bath framework to achieve this`? How/When are you planning to consume the results? You said have a large number of items to process, where are you going to write them (ie to a persistent store or an in-memory one)? Have you thought about restartability in case of failure? Those are important details to choose the right solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine for your response. I updated the original post to answer your first 2 questions. About question: You said have a large number of items to process, where are you going to write them (ie to a persistent store or an in-memory one)? Have you thought about restartability in case of failure?: I am planning to write all success/failure item IDs to job execution context using a persistent store. Job is restartable, when it is restarted using the same parameters, it will first read the job execution context and get all the items which failed and reprocess only these items.

Comment: I mean are you going to write the items themselves to a persistent store? The item writer is required in a chunk-oriented step and the solution depends on how you are going to write items (also, is the success/failure status just a flag? or a different object with more information?, etc). Where those items are going to be written? A table, a file, to the standard output with System.out ? Please share your code to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: success/failure status is just a flag like 1/0. I am going to save item IDs with the success/failure flag to job execution context which will be saved to spring batch table. At the end of the job, I just need the item IDs with success/failure flags. I can do it easily by looking up the spring batch tables. Hope this answers your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still did not answer the question about which item writer you are going to use, so I will try to answer your question and show you why this detail is key to choose the right solution to your problem.

Here is your requirement:

```
I have a spring batch job. It processes a large number of items.
For each item, it calls an external service (assume a stored procedure
or a REST service. This does some business calculations and updates a database.
```

In your description, you are talking about storing item IDs with their status in the job execution context. While this is possible, what I'm saying is that if you are going to write items to a table anyway in which you have a column with a status flag, you don't need to use the job execution context at all. Hence my question:

```
are you going to write the items themselves to a persistent store?
The item writer is required in a chunk-oriented step and the solution
depends on how you are going to write items (also, is the success/failure
status just a flag? or a different object with more information?, etc).
Where those items are going to be written? A table, a file, to the standard
output with System.out ?
```

So I will assume you going to write items to table having a status column since you said `This does some business calculations and updates a database`.

You can use an item processor to do the business logic and flag item with their status (ie your domain object has a flag `status` that the processor sets as needed). The item writer then updates items in the database with their status. This approach solves all issues listed above by design as it does not require the job execution context and is a good option for a multi-threaded or partitioned step (since items are independent).

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying earlier. Currently, each worker step is a Tasklet which just calls external service and receives a SUCCESS/FAILURE flag. I want to store each item ID with flag. Assume that if I did not have a partitioned/multithreaded steps then I could have gotten away with storing the item ID and its flag in job execution context. When the job was completed, I could read this spring batch table and get all item IDs with the flags. But that does not work with partitioned job and I have this overhead of creating an external table just to store item ID and SUCCESS/FAILURE flag.